# How do I remove the Slice<> from a ClosedRange.SubSequence?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the [chunked method in Swift Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms).

When I work on a Range, it's pretty easy to handle the resulting type:

```
let range: Range<Int> = 0..<5
let subRangesIntermediary: [Range<Int>.SubSequence] = range.chunked(on: { $0 / 2 })
assert(Range<Int>.SubSequence.self == Range<Int>.self)

let subRanges: [Range<Int>] = subRangesIntermediary
assert(subRanges == [0..<2, 2..<4, 4..<5])
```

That's because `Range<Int>.SubSequence == Range<Int>` so converting between the two is effortless.

When I try to do the same thing with `ClosedRange`, I run into problems:

```
let closedRange: ClosedRange<Int> = 0...4
let subClosedRangesIntermediary: [ClosedRange<Int>.SubSequence] = closedRange.chunked(on: { $0 / 2})
let subClosedRangesIntermediary2: [Slice<ClosedRange<Int>>] = subClosedRangesIntermediary
// assert(subClosedRangesIntermediary2 == [0...1, 2...3, 4...4]) // ❌ Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Slice<ClosedRange<Int>>]' and 'ArraySlice<ClosedRange<Int>>'
```

That's because `ClosedRange<Int>.SubSequence == Slice<ClosedRange<Int>>`.

I'm looking to remove the Slice so that I'm left with an array of `ClosedRange`.

I figured out a way to do it manually, but this looks like a lot of work:

```
let subClosedRanges: [ClosedRange<Int>] = subClosedRangesIntermediary2.map {
  let start = closedRange[$0.startIndex]
  let end = closedRange[$0.index(before: $0.endIndex)]
  return start...end
}
assert(subClosedRanges == [0...1, 2...3, 4...4])
```

I was hoping there is a way to do something like the following instead:

```
let subClosedRanges: [ClosedRange<Int>] = subClosedRangesIntermediary2.map { $0.valueInBase }
```

or:

```
// Similar to how we can use Array(slice) on ArraySlice:
let subClosedRanges: [ClosedRange<Int>] = subClosedRangesIntermediary2.map { ClosedRange($0) }
```

I couldn't find anything like that for [Slice](https://swiftdoc.org/v4.2/type/slice/).

How do I convert a `Slice<ClosedRange<T>>` to a `ClosedRange<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring a more authoritative answer, here is a workaround:

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound: Strideable, Bound.Stride: SignedInteger {
  init(_ slice: Slice<Self>) {
    let lower = slice.base[slice.startIndex]
    let upper = slice.base[slice.index(before: slice.endIndex)]
    self.init(uncheckedBounds: (lower: lower, upper: upper))
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let subClosedRanges: [ClosedRange<Int>] = subClosedRangesIntermediary2.map { ClosedRange($0) }
```

Comment: Another possible approach is `slice.first!...slice.last!`... `!` I think is justified here because it's guaranteed that a `ClosedRange` is never empty

Comment: @NewDev: `self.init(uncheckedBounds: (lower: slice.first!, upper: slice.last!))` works too. Thanks for the suggestion.